# Call to a member function getKey() on string when collecting an array

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to turn an associative array into a collection in order to merge it with another collection, but for some reason I'm getting the following error:

```
Call to a member function getKey() on string
```

My code:

```
$posts = Post::with(['category', 'user'])->get();

$toMerge = collect([ 'video' => '/img/misc/doggo.mp4', 'component' => 'slider-item-2' ]);

$mergedPosts = $posts->merge($toMerge);
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that $posts is a Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object which override the merge method of the base base collection Illuminate\Support\Collection.

The merge method of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection expect another Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection.

You need to reverse your merge:

```
$mergedPosts = $toMerge->merge($posts);
```